# Outputting results to Pipe delimited format adding extra space

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

After unsuccessfully using SQL Manager's output options I am hardcoding in pipes to make the output pipe delimited. The problem is that there is a space being added between the pipe and the next column. I've tried LTRIM function and that did not remove the spaces.

```
SELECT B.BUSINESS_UNIT+'|'
       , C.DESCR+'|'
       , (CONVERT(CHAR(10),B.INVOICE_DT,121) + '|')
       , CAST(B.INVOICE_ID AS varchar) + '|'
       , CAST(A.LINE_NBR AS varchar) + '|'
       , CAST(B.GROSS_AMT AS varchar) + '|'
       , CAST(B.VENDOR_ID AS varchar) + '|'
       , D.NAME1 + '|'
       , CAST(M.ITM_ID_VNDR AS varchar) + '|'
       , J.DESCR + '|'
FROM Some_Table1 B 
     , SomeTable2 C
     , SomeTable3 A
     , SomeTable4 D
     , SomeTable5 J
     , SomeTable6 M
```

If I copy the results to a text editor there is a space between the pipe and the next column.

Comment: Not sure about SQL Server but instead of `B.BUSINESS_UNIT+'|',C.DESCR+'|',...` can't you `B.BUSINESS_UNIT+'|'+C.DESCR+'|'+...` or `CONCAT(B.BUSINESS_UNIT,'|',C.DESCR,'|',...)`

Comment: @Nick, please add your result in your question. That is how we can help you better and maybe faster :) Thanks!

Comment: Yes -- to clarify a little bit, you are selecting 9 columns and adding pipe characters.  Instead you want to select a single column with the pipe characters added the way @JerryJeremiah shows.

Comment: I have understood that the only problem is that the result has space between column value and a '|' (pipe sign). It is not important how you resolve the pipe part, it is important to remove the spaces... That is how I got it.

Comment: I did try formatting as just 1 long column however then I get some rows that are just completely NULL, I think possibly because 1 or more of the columns on certain rows have some null values.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a space. It's probably a tab.

When you copy a row from the `Results` pane of SSMS and paste the row into a text editor, or at least into Notepad++, it injects a tab between columns. Turn on `Show All Characters` or the equivalent to verify.

You can get around that by following Jerry Jeremiah's suggestion in the comments and reducing your output to a single long row:

```
SELECT CONCAT(B.BUSINESS_UNIT,'|',
              C.DESCR,'|',
              CONVERT(CHAR(10),B.INVOICE_DT,121),'|',
              B.INVOICE_ID,'|' 
              etc.)
```

And [`CONCAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is your friend here. It takes care of all of the data type conversions for you, except those edge cases like `INVOICE_DT` where you want a `CHAR` (although I think an implicit conversion to `varchar(x)` here would give you the results you're expecting).

Also, as an aside, be cautious casting to `varchar` without declaring a length. If you do it in the wrong place, it can default to `varchar(1)`, which is seldom what anybody wants. See [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: Thanks for putting an answer.  I like helping but seldom have time to write a nicely though out answer.

Comment: I’m often in the same boat. I did try to expand on things enough that I wasn’t just hijacking your comment as an answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What will this do if it encounters a `NULL` in one or more of the columns?

Comment: You'll get two adjacent pipes with nothing between them.

Comment: Also, if you're going to be doing this frequently, or need to operationalize it so you're not copying and pasting all day long, SSIS eats this kind of task for breakfast.

Comment: Interesting, I used this method, but when I output as a single long row it returns some NULL rows (entire row is NULL), whereas before I may have had some null columns within a row, but the entire row was not null.

Comment: My comment about `NULL`s was incomplete. Using `+` to concatenate strings, a single `NULL` element will cause the whole concatenation to be `NULL`. If you want to use `+`, or have to because you have more than 254 elements to concatenate, each nullable element has to be wrapped in an `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` to avoid that behavior. Using the `CONCAT` function, a `NULL` element returns an empty string at that location in the concatenation.